# How to Convert PDF to Image using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, powerapps

I'm trying to use a Logic App to convert a PDF File into an Image (JPG). I did every configuration with this article showed but it's not working. When I send it to API, that returns this error:

[image: My Flow]

[image: Error]

Comment: "with this article showed" - where is this article? Have you provided a link?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is a fix. I have raised a [thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/document-services-apis/logic-app-connectors-not-working/m-p/11765639?page=1#M1119) in the Adobe Forum as well

I switched the logic app to code view

[image]

I moved the below piece of code

```
{
                                "body": "JPEG",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"targetFormat\""
                                }
                            },
```

Above :

```
{
                                "body": "this ith",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"InputFile0\""
                                }
                            },
```

Final Version :
[image]

Save it, Don't switch it to designer view. Run the Flow. You will be able to run the flow without the above error.

Comment: I still don't see the output even if the document has been processed. seems like the connector is broken or service side issue.